# Javascript JSX, illegal import declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

I have a jsx file using React components with Reflux. There is only one tiny action:

```
var ClickedAction = Reflux.createActions([
  'clicked'
]);
```

How can I move this action to another file? According to the [JSX documentation](https://jsx.github.io/doc/importref.html), it should be easy to include other files:

> // import all classes that do not start with "_" from "a.jsx"
>
> import "a.jsx";

I tried to move it in actions/clickedAction.jsx (or .js) and import it using `import "actions/clickedActions.jsx"` but I keep getting `Illegal import declaration`. How can I achieve this?

I am not using RequireJS and would like to avoid it if possible. One alternative solution I have found is to include this in the HTML file,

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='xxxxx/actions/clickedAction.js")'></script>
```

, but this is not ideal and would like to find another way. Thanks for your attention and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Babel:

```
export default ClickedAction; // in action file
```

Otherwise, use old modules:

```
module.exports = ClickedAction; // in action file

require('actions/clickedActions.jsx');  // in another file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any ways to achieve this without RequireJS?

Comment: You can use webpack to build applications. Or any other tools .JS does not have modules that work without build tools.